# Create a JSON column in BigQuery with the actual column values as keys

Tags: google-bigquery

**Is there a way to create a JSON in BigQuery with the column values as the keys?**

I have 3 columns in the table:

```
user_id (string) | category (string) | info (struct)

user_1, cat_A, info_1A
user_1, cat_B, info_1B
user_1, cat_C, info_1C
user_2, cat_A, info_2A
user_3, cat_Z, info_3Z
user_3, cat_B, info_3B

To abbreviate the values of the "info" column,
let's say that it is a struct of i.e. {'f': 2, 'c': 3, ...}
```

I wanted to have this output, where the *keys* of the "features" column are the actual values of the "category" column:

```
user_id (string) | features (struct/JSON)
user_1, {cat_A: info_1A, cat_B: info_1B, cat_C: info_1C, ...}
user_2, {cat_A: info_2A}
user_3, {cat_Z: info_3Z, cat_B: info_3B}
```

But instead, I'm currently only able to achieve this format (I made the output JSON-formatted for more clarity), where the *keys* are the pre-defined name you give when creating the STRUCT with i.e. `STRUCT(...) AS *key*`:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "user_1",
    "features": [
      {
        "category": "cat_A",
        "features": {
          "f": 2,
          "c": 3,
        }
      },
      {
        "category": "cat_B",
        "features": {
          "x": 7,
          "z": 10,
        }
      },
      ...
  }
  ...
]
```

By using the query below:

```sql
SELECT
  user_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(
      category,
      STRUCT(f, c, x, z) AS features -- the different features for each category
    )
  )
FROM ...
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, '{' || STRING_AGG(category || ': ' || info, ', ') || '}' features
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY user_id
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'user_1' user_id, 'cat_A' category, 'info_1A' info UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_1', 'cat_B', 'info_1B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_1', 'cat_C', 'info_1C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_2', 'cat_A', 'info_2A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_3', 'cat_Z', 'info_3Z' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'user_3', 'cat_B', 'info_3B' 
)
SELECT user_id, '{' || STRING_AGG(category || ': ' || info, ', ') || '}' features
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY user_id
```

with output

```
Row user_id features     
1   user_1  {cat_A: info_1A, cat_B: info_1B, cat_C: info_1C}     
2   user_2  {cat_A: info_2A}     
3   user_3  {cat_Z: info_3Z, cat_B: info_3B}
```